# How to fix AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed

Tags: java, minecraft

I am currently working on a custom pvp client for minecraft version 1.8.8. every time I attempt to launch the client from Eclipse, go to singleplayer, and open a world, the client crashes and my Eclipse console gives me this. "AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed." Here is the minecraft crash report.

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// Don't be sad, have a hug! <3

Time: 8/8/21, 3:06 PM
Description: Unexpected error

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void net.minecraft.client.renderer.EntityRenderer$1.<init>(net.minecraft.client.renderer.EntityRenderer)'
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.EntityRenderer.getMouseOver(EntityRenderer.java:495)
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.EntityRenderer.renderWorld(EntityRenderer.java:1504)
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.EntityRenderer.func_181560_a(EntityRenderer.java:1326)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.runGameLoop(Minecraft.java:1129)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:421)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:113)
    at Start.main(Start.java:11)
```

### A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:

```
-- Head --
Stacktrace:
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.EntityRenderer.getMouseOver(EntityRenderer.java:495)
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.EntityRenderer.renderWorld(EntityRenderer.java:1504)

-- Affected level --
Details:
    Level name: MpServer
    All players: 1 total; [EntityPlayerSP['Player703'/154, l='MpServer', x=232.50, y=67.00, z=260.50]]
    Chunk stats: MultiplayerChunkCache: 0, 0
    Level seed: 0
    Level generator: ID 00 - default, ver 1. Features enabled: false
    Level generator options: 
    Level spawn location: 224.00,64.00,256.00 - World: (224,64,256), Chunk: (at 0,4,0 in 14,16; contains blocks 224,0,256 to 239,255,271), Region: (0,0; contains chunks 0,0 to 31,31, blocks 0,0,0 to 511,255,511)
    Level time: 9 game time, 9 day time
    Level dimension: 0
    Level storage version: 0x00000 - Unknown?
    Level weather: Rain time: 0 (now: false), thunder time: 0 (now: false)
    Level game mode: Game mode: creative (ID 1). Hardcore: false. Cheats: false
    Forced entities: 1 total; [EntityPlayerSP['Player703'/154, l='MpServer', x=232.50, y=67.00, z=260.50]]
    Retry entities: 0 total; []
    Server brand: vanilla
    Server type: Integrated singleplayer server
Stacktrace:
    at net.minecraft.client.multiplayer.WorldClient.addWorldInfoToCrashReport(WorldClient.java:401)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.addGraphicsAndWorldToCrashReport(Minecraft.java:2747)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:450)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:113)
    at Start.main(Start.java:11)

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.8.8
    Operating System: Windows 10 (amd64) version 10.0
    CPU: 4x AMD Ryzen 3 3200G with Radeon Vega Graphics 
    Java Version: 16.0.2, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 916995936 bytes (874 MB) / 1073741824 bytes (1024 MB) up to 1073741824 bytes (1024 MB)
    JVM Flags: 3 total; -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 12, tallocated: 94
    Launched Version: mcp
    LWJGL: 2.9.4
    OpenGL: AMD 15D8:C9 GL version 4.6.14736 Compatibility Profile Context 20.10.1 27.20.12033.1007, ATI Technologies Inc.
    GL Caps: Using GL 1.3 multitexturing.
Using GL 1.3 texture combiners.
Using framebuffer objects because OpenGL 3.0 is supported and separate blending is supported.
Shaders are available because OpenGL 2.1 is supported.
VBOs are available because OpenGL 1.5 is supported.

    Using VBOs: No
    Is Modded: Very likely; Jar signature invalidated
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Resource Packs: 
    Current Language: English (US)
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
    CPU: 4x AMD Ryzen 3 3200G with Radeon Vega Graphics 
    OptiFine Version: OptiFine_1.8.8_HD_U_H8
    Render Distance Chunks: 12
    Mipmaps: 4
    Anisotropic Filtering: 1
    Antialiasing: 0
    Multitexture: false
    Shaders: null
    OpenGlVersion: 4.6.14736 Compatibility Profile Context 20.10.1 27.20.12033.1007
    OpenGlRenderer: AMD 15D8:C9
    OpenGlVendor: ATI Technologies Inc.
    CpuCount: 4
```

If you need more information, please let me know. I am a bit new to Java.

Comment: What changes have you made? Specifically, can you show us the code at and surrounding line 495 in the file `EntityRenderer.java`?

Comment: @ErikKarlstrand   Vec3 vec32 = vec3.addVector(vec31.xCoord * d0, vec31.yCoord * d0, vec31.zCoord * d0);
            this.pointedEntity = null;
            Vec3 vec33 = null;
            float f = 1.0F;
            List list = this.mc.theWorld.getEntitiesInAABBexcluding(entity, entity.getEntityBoundingBox().addCoord(vec31.xCoord * d0, vec31.yCoord * d0, vec31.zCoord * d0).expand((double)f, (double)f, (double)f), Predicates.and(EntitySelectors.NOT_SPECTATING, new EntityRenderer$1(this)));
            double d2 = d1;

Comment: Did you write this particular code?
Specifically this part looks quite suspicious: `new EntityRenderer$1(this)`

Comment: no, it was already like that. i didnt touch anything in entity renderer

Comment: Alright, what changes have you made then?

Comment: i created 2 new classes for a discord rich presence, and i added to minecraft.java so it would detect when im on a server, in singleplayer, ect. i also used vecmath to add optifine to it, which i think optifine might be part of the issue. i get dozens of missing texture errors in my console when i launch the client.